# Global check of input/output of known hash functions

Tags: hash, reverse-engineering

Is there a website, application, or script that will allow you to give an input/output for a hash function, run these against known functions, and return any matches?

Here's one attempt to list the functions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you wanting to give the input and output to identify the function or give the output and function to get the input?

Comment: @Rory Alsop: Yes, give the input and output to identify the function. Basically, the input is processed via each hash function, the checked to see if the hash's output matches the output supplied. If it does, it's flagged as a match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hash ID is a new, open sourced, project trying to achieve exactly the thing that you are looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/

Encryption formats supported:

```
ADLER-32
CRC-32
CRC-32B
CRC-16
CRC-16-CCITT
DES(Unix)
FCS-16
GHash-32-3
GHash-32-5
GOST R 34.11-94
Haval-160
Haval-192 110080 ,Haval-224 114080 ,Haval-256
Lineage II C4
Domain Cached Credentials
XOR-32
MD5(Half)
MD5(Middle)
MySQL
MD5(phpBB3)
MD5(Unix)
MD5(Wordpress)
MD5(APR)
Haval-128
MD2
MD4
MD5
MD5(HMAC(Wordpress))
NTLM
RAdmin v2.x
RipeMD-128
SNEFRU-128
Tiger-128
MySQL5 - SHA-1(SHA-1($pass))
MySQL 160bit - SHA-1(SHA-1($pass))
RipeMD-160
SHA-1
SHA-1(MaNGOS)
Tiger-160
Tiger-192
md5($pass.$salt) - Joomla
SHA-1(Django)
SHA-224
RipeMD-256
SNEFRU-256
md5($pass.$salt) - Joomla
SAM - (LM_hash:NT_hash)
SHA-256(Django)
RipeMD-320
SHA-384
SHA-256
SHA-384(Django)
SHA-512
Whirlpool
And more…
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 7):

You mean that you want to give the input and the output, and then a site / app / whatever gives you what hash function was used?

I don't know any that does exactly that. But there is the http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm that calculates a lots of hashes formats for a given input. It gives you:

Adler32
CRC32
Haval
MD2
MD4
MD5
RipeMD128
RipeMD160
SHA-1
SHA-256
SHA-384
SHA-512
Tiger
Whirlpool

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [sphlib](http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/): this is a library implementing many cryptographic hash functions under a common API, and there is a command-line tool tool which ressembles the classic `md5sum` / `sha1sum`. It is written in C, but there is also a Java version which would be rather easy to turn into an applet for a Web site.